# How can I detect a new SageMaker model deployed to a model group using an event pattern?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, aws-event-bridge

I'm trying to create an EventBridge rule for detecting a 'SageMaker Model Package Group State Change'.

In other words, I want to detect when a new model version is put into a SageMaker Model Package Group called `WineQualityPackageGroup-2` with a status of `PendingManualApproval`.

I have the following event pattern:

```json
{
  "source": ["aws.sagemaker"],
  "detail-type": ["SageMaker Model Package Group State Change"],
  "resources": ["arn:aws:sagemaker:eu-west-2:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:model-package-group/WineQualityPackageGroup-2"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["sagemaker.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["CreateModelPackage"],
    "requestParameters": {
      "modelPackageGroupName": ["WineQualityPackageGroup-2"],
      "modelPackageStatus": ["PendingManualApproval"]
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I run my ML training pipeline, which registers a new model version into the model package group, the rule is not triggered.

Looking at the Cloudtrail logs and searching for the events that happen, I was able to detect the `CreateModelPackage` event and the event record.

As follows:

```json
{
    "eventVersion": "1.09",
    "userIdentity": {
        "type": "AssumedRole",
        "principalId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:sagemaker-pipeline-v4uj8jokqgew-WineQualityRegisterR",
        "arn": "arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/SageMakerExecutionRole-ModelBuild-CICD/sagemaker-pipeline-v4uj8jokqgew-WineQualityRegisterR",
        "accountId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "accessKeyId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "sessionContext": {
            "sessionIssuer": {
                "type": "Role",
                "principalId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "arn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/SageMakerExecutionRole-ModelBuild-CICD",
                "accountId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "userName": "SageMakerExecutionRole-ModelBuild-CICD"
            },
            "attributes": {
                "creationDate": "2023-10-10T10:13:51Z",
                "mfaAuthenticated": "false"
            }
        },
        "invokedBy": "pipelines.sagemaker.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "eventTime": "2023-10-10T10:13:52Z",
    "eventSource": "sagemaker.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "CreateModelPackage",
    "awsRegion": "eu-west-2",
    "sourceIPAddress": "pipelines.sagemaker.amazonaws.com",
    "userAgent": "pipelines.sagemaker.amazonaws.com",
    "requestParameters": {
        "modelPackageGroupName": "WineQualityPackageGroup-2",
        "inferenceSpecification": {
            "containers": [
                {
                    "image": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-scikit-learn:1.2-1-cpu-py3",
                    "modelDataUrl": "s3://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/WineQualityPipeline-ModelBuild/v4uj8jokqgew/WineQualityPredict/RandomForestClassifier/pipelines-v4uj8jokqgew-TrainingRandomForest-3xiWRJSszB/output/model.tar.gz",
                    "environment": {
                        "SAGEMAKER_SUBMIT_DIRECTORY": "",
                        "SAGEMAKER_CONTAINER_LOG_LEVEL": "20",
                        "SAGEMAKER_REGION": "eu-west-2",
                        "SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM": ""
                    },
                    "framework": "SKLEARN"
                }
            ],
            "supportedTransformInstanceTypes": [
                "ml.m5.xlarge"
            ],
            "supportedRealtimeInferenceInstanceTypes": [
                "ml.t2.medium",
                "ml.m5.xlarge"
            ],
            "supportedContentTypes": [
                "text/csv"
            ],
            "supportedResponseMIMETypes": [
                "text/csv"
            ]
        },
        "certifyForMarketplace": false,
        "requireImageScan": false,
        "modelApprovalStatus": "PendingManualApproval",
        "metadataProperties": {
            "generatedBy": "arn:aws:sagemaker:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:pipeline/winequalitypipeline-modelbuild/execution/v4uj8jokqgew"
        },
        "clientToken": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "responseElements": {
        "modelPackageArn": "arn:aws:sagemaker:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:model-package/WineQualityPackageGroup-2/3"
    },
    "requestID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "eventID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "readOnly": false,
    "resources": [
        {
            "accountId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "type": "AWS::SageMaker::ModelPackageGroup",
            "ARN": "arn:aws:sagemaker:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:model-package-group/WineQualityPackageGroup-2"
        },
        {
            "accountId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "type": "AWS::SageMaker::ModelPackage",
            "ARN": "arn:aws:sagemaker:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:model-package/WineQualityPackageGroup-2/3"
        }
    ],
    "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
    "managementEvent": true,
    "recipientAccountId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "eventCategory": "Management"
}
```

As suggested in comments, the event as logged in a CloudWatch log group is also as follows:

```json
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "9bc9e0a0-e4e8-0b2f-c3b1-d7074b281af1",
    "detail-type": "SageMaker Model Package State Change",
    "source": "aws.sagemaker",
    "account": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "time": "2023-10-10T15:33:30Z",
    "region": "eu-west-2",
    "resources": [
        "arn:aws:sagemaker:eu-west-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:model-package/WineQualityPackageGroup-2/7"
    ],
    "detail": {
        "ModelPackageName": "WineQualityPackageGroup-2/7",
        "ModelPackageGroupName": "WineQualityPackageGroup-2",
        "ModelPackageVersion": 7,
        "ModelPackageArn": "arn:aws:sagemaker:eu-west-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:model-package/WineQualityPackageGroup-2/7",
        "ModelPackageDescription": null,
        "CreationTime": 1696952010090,
        "InferenceSpecification": {
            "Containers": [
                {
                    "ContainerHostname": null,
                    "Image": "XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-scikit-learn:1.2-1-cpu-py3",
                    "ImageDigest": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "ModelDataUrl": "s3://XXXXXXXXXXXX/WineQualityPipeline-ModelBuild/sovgi0o5mv4j/WineQualityPredict/RandomForestClassifier/pipelines-sovgi0o5mv4j-TrainingRandomForest-mdiXKAFvui/output/model.tar.gz",
                    "ProductId": null,
                    "Environment": null,
                    "ModelInput": null,
                    "Framework": null,
                    "FrameworkVersion": null,
                    "NearestModelName": null,
                    "SamplePayloadUrl": null,
                    "AdditionalS3DataSource": null
                }
            ],
            "SupportedTransformInstanceTypes": [
                "ml.m5.xlarge"
            ],
            "SupportedRealtimeInferenceInstanceTypes": [
                "ml.t2.medium",
                "ml.m5.xlarge"
            ],
            "SupportedContentTypes": [
                "text/csv"
            ],
            "SupportedResponseMIMETypes": [
                "text/csv"
            ]
        },
        "SourceAlgorithmSpecification": null,
        "ValidationSpecification": null,
        "ModelPackageStatus": "Created",
        "ModelPackageStatusDetails": {
            "ValidationStatuses": [],
            "ImageScanStatuses": []
        },
        "CertifyForMarketplace": false,
        "ModelApprovalStatus": "PendingManualApproval",
        "CreatedBy": {
            "UserProfileArn": null,
            "UserProfileName": null,
            "DomainId": null,
            "IamIdentity": {
                "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/SageMakerExecutionRole-ModelBuild-CICD/sagemaker-pipeline-sovgi0o5mv4j-WineQualityRegisterR",
                "PrincipalId": "XXXXXXXXXXXX:sagemaker-pipeline-sovgi0o5mv4j-WineQualityRegisterR",
                "SourceIdentity": null
            }
        },
        "MetadataProperties": null,
        "ModelMetrics": null,
        "DeploymentSpecification": null,
        "LastModifiedTime": null,
        "LastModifiedBy": {
            "UserProfileArn": null,
            "UserProfileName": null,
            "DomainId": null,
            "IamIdentity": {
                "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/SageMakerExecutionRole-ModelBuild-CICD/sagemaker-pipeline-sovgi0o5mv4j-WineQualityRegisterR",
                "PrincipalId": "XXXXXXXXXXXX:sagemaker-pipeline-sovgi0o5mv4j-WineQualityRegisterR",
                "SourceIdentity": null
            }
        },
        "ApprovalDescription": null,
        "Domain": null,
        "Task": null,
        "SamplePayloadUrl": null,
        "SamplePayloadContentType": null,
        "CustomerMetadataProperties": null,
        "DriftCheckBaselines": null,
        "AdditionalInferenceSpecifications": null,
        "SkipModelValidation": null
    }
}
```

Why is the event pattern not matching the event that triggers when a new model version is put in the package group?

Comment: To debug, create a new rule where the `source` is `aws.sagemaker`. Designate a CloudWatch log group as the target. Run your pipeline & then check the log group. You’re looking for an event that has ‘SageMaker Model Package (Group?) State Change’ in it. Do you see anything?

Comment: Yes, I see an event with that name: SageMaker Model Package State Change.

Comment: Can you please add the event contents to the question?

Comment: Just added the contents of the event logged to cloudwatch group as suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the event pattern not matching the event that triggers when a new model version is put in the package group?

You have [2 'types of events'](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-service-event.html) that you can have an EventBridge rule match against:

- service events generated by the service itself
- CloudTrail events, delivered to EventBridge via a [trail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-concepts.html#cloudtrail-concepts-trails)

The event pattern you’re using actually doesn't match either of the above.

Your event pattern is semantically correct, but your event is a raw CloudTrail event. This type of event won’t be delivered to EventBridge, and even if it were, it wouldn’t match your pattern.

A CloudTrail event would only be sent to EventBridge if you create a [trail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-concepts.html#cloudtrail-concepts-trails) (that's the whole purpose of a trail). In that case, AWS (EventBridge) would - [at a minimum](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-events-structure.html#eb-custom-event) - add the extra fields of `source`, `detail-type` and `detail` to the event for use in the event pattern.

Your event doesn’t contain these fields, which means it's from CloudTrail and wouldn’t be sent to EventBridge at all, let alone in the above format. For example, as per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-service-event.html#eb-service-event-cloudtrail), all events that are delivered by CloudTrail to EventBridge have `AWS API Call via CloudTrail` as the value for `detail-type`. That field doesn't exist in your event.

In reality, none of the fields in your current event pattern match the above event object (the non-augmented CloudTrail event) and even if they did, it'd be futile as the above event in the above format would never be sent to EventBridge.

And even if you created a trail for it to be sent (and augmented with extra fields) as an event that could be pattern-matched against, the pattern wouldn’t match the non-existent `detail-type` value of ‘SageMaker Model Package Group State Change’.

That's why the event pattern doesn't work as:

1. it doesn't match the event
2. this is the wrong event to match against

> I want to detect when a new model version is put into a SageMaker Model Package Group called `WineQualityPackageGroup-2` with a status of `PendingManualApproval`.

*Sagemaker Model State Changes* are a [supported service event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/automating-sagemaker-with-eventbridge.html#eventbridge-model) so go with option 1.

It's easier to create an event pattern for a service event & you don't need to create a separate trail or incur costs for CloudTrail events being stored in an S3 bucket. However note for future reference that [not all services support EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-service-event-list.html) natively. That's why option 2 exists.

Using a demo catch-all event pattern to log this in CloudWatch has highlighted the `ModelPackageGroupName` field in the nested `detail` object, that you can use to essentially track *SageMaker Model State Changes* at a package group level i.e. *SageMaker Model Package Group State Change*.

Let's build the event pattern bit by bit.

> a new model version

```json
{
  "source": ["aws.sagemaker"],
  "detail-type": ["SageMaker Model Package State Change"],
  "detail": {
    "ModelPackageStatus": ["Created"]
  }
}
```

> ... is put into a SageMaker Model Package Group called `WineQualityPackageGroup-2`

```json
{
  "source": ["aws.sagemaker"],
  "detail-type": ["SageMaker Model Package State Change"],
  "detail": {
    "ModelPackageStatus": ["Created"],
    "ModelPackageGroupName": ["WineQualityPackageGroup-2"]
  }
}
```

> ... with a status of `PendingManualApproval`

```json
{
  "source": ["aws.sagemaker"],
  "detail-type": ["SageMaker Model Package State Change"],
  "detail": {
    "ModelPackageStatus": ["Created"],
    "ModelPackageGroupName": ["WineQualityPackageGroup-2"],
    "ModelApprovalStatus": ["PendingManualApproval"]
  }
}
```

The above event pattern applied to your rule should catch the events you're looking for.